Differing behaviors in Popen.readline() between IDE and terminal runs
I have a Tkinter GUI program that I would like to update a text Frame on with output from a called process. I managed to make it work pretty well using threading and subprocess, with the 'run' button bound to a method to create a thread and call Popen within it.
def template_thread(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.run_template, daemon=True).start()

The run_template method calls main.py with the path to a config file as an arg:
p = subprocess.Popen([EXE, FIRST_RUN, os.path.join(self.output.get(), 'runtime.ini')],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)

while p.poll() is None:
    print('here')
    #p.stdout.flush()
    #p.stderr.flush()
    msg = p.stdout.readline()
    err = p.stderr.readline()
    if msg:
        self.output_window.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")
    if err:
        with open(os.path.join(self.output.get(), 'LOG.txt'), 'a') as log:
            log.write(err)

This works perfectly whenever I test it within Pycharm, but as soon as I try to run it from anywhere else, the behavior changes to blocking on the readline() until the process has finished, and then flushing the whole stdout to the text Frame at once. I think from other similar but very old questions that it has to do with how the buffer is set by each program and somehow the IDE terminal is setting the buffer to flush and newlines but can't find a solution. Running with '-u' as an argument didn't seem to have an effect and neither did adding 'flush=True' to the first print statement. The program works as needed otherwise and the mainloop is not interrupted as I can see the focus on my widgets changing so I'm a little stumped. Running on Windows if that changes anything. Any help is appreciated!

As a side note, you MUST NOT update your GUI from a secondary thread.  That is prohibited on all platforms.  It sometimes works on Windows, which gives people a false sense of security, but it usually fails on Linux and always fails on MacOS.  Use after to update the UI.

@TimRoberts are you suggesting this as a fix or just best-use advice?

After looking into @TimRoberts comment I managed to make it work using after() and two more threads to read and write to a queue. The relevant class methods are:
    def update_window(self):
        try:
            msg = self.queue.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            msg = None

        if msg:
            self.output_window.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")

        if msg != '__EXIT__':
            self.root.after(1000, self.update_window)

    def run_template(self, queue, control_queue):

        p = subprocess.Popen([EXE, FIRST_RUN, os.path.join(self.output.get(), 'runtime.ini')], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)

        listner = threading.Thread(target=update_queue, args=[p.stdout, queue], daemon=True)
        listner.start()

        p.wait()

        if p.returncode != 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Runtime Error", "Error has occurred during runtime")
            with open(os.path.join(self.output.get(), 'LOG.txt'), 'a') as log:
                log.write(p.stderr.read())
            control_queue.put('Unlock')
        else:
            ret = messagebox.askyesno("Process Completed", "Run Again?")
            if ret:
                control_queue.put('Unlock')
            else:
                control_queue.put('Exit')

        queue.put('__EXIT__')


    def template_thread(self):
        self.lock_widgets(self.root)
        proc = self.root.after(1000, self.update_window)
        proc2 = self.root.after(1000, self.control_listener)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_template, args=[self.queue, self.control_queue], daemon=True).start()

and one static function:
def update_queue(pipe, queue):
    while True:
        line = pipe.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        queue.put(line)

This seems to be working pretty well but I'm not sure if its the best way so I'll leave the question open.

JUST FOR THE RECORD, you're still doing UI stiff in a secondary thread (specifically, the two messagebox calls), but because messagebox creates a modal dialog, it has its own main loop, and therefore is OK in a thread.
